# Pseudo code for array conversion

Tags: arrays, verilog

Is this pseudo code correct to convert 2D array into 1D in Verilog:

```
wire [Width*Depth-1:0]One_D_array;
genvar i;
for (i=0; i<Depth; i=i+1) 
assign One_D_array[Width*i+Depth-1:Width*i] = A[i];
```

And to reconvert into array:

```
wire [Width-1:0]local_2D_array[0:Depth-1];
integer i;
for (i=0;i<Depth;i=i+1) 
assign local_2D_array[i] = input[Width*i+Width-1:Width*i];
```

Comment: `integer` needs to be `genvar` in order to compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working correctly. First code will be making all array members into series. And in next part of code, which is reconstruction part, we will be splitting data into members. It works for any width and any depth.